# Return elements of the array that form a sum

Tags: java

I wrote the below code to see if an array has 2 numbers that account to a sum. I don't know how to capture the elements that contribute to that sum. Any thoughts

Example = {1,11,4,7,8,10} Sum = 21 Count=2

This code returns true or false but does not capture the numbers that contribute to the sum. How can I do that?

```
public static boolean isSum(int[] a,int val,int count,int index){
    if(count == 0 && val ==0){
        return true;
    }
    if(index>=a.length)
        return false;
    else{
        return isSum(a,val-a[index],count-1,index+1)||isSum(a,val,count,index+1);
    }
}
```

I appreciate all the beautiful solutions listed below. Was hacking around in the morning and found an elegant way to solve this problem for any number of elements that can account to the sum. Just wanted to share the solution here for your comments

```
public class IsSum {

static ArrayList<Integer> intArray;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] a = {1,44, 4, 7, 8, 10};
    intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (isSum(a,54,2, 0)) {
        System.out.println("Is Present");
    }
    Iterator<Integer> arrayIter = intArray.iterator();
    while (arrayIter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(arrayIter.next());
    }
}

public static boolean isSum(int[] a, int val, int count, int index) {
    if (count == 0 && val == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (index >= a.length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (isSum(a, val - a[index], count - 1, index + 1)) {
            intArray.add(a[index]);
            return true;
        } else {
            return isSum(a, val, count, index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "2 numbers that account to a sum" ?

Comment: Could you give an example? I am not able to understand what you mean

Comment: Ive added an example. Sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: do you want to have the numbers that makes the sum ??

Comment: ie if sum =21 then it must return 10 and 11.. Is that what you are looking for..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Class used to hold the result details.
 */
private static class Result {
    boolean isSum;

    int[][] pairs;

    int noOfPairs;

    Result(int value) {
        pairs = new int[value][2];
    }
}

public static Result isSum(int[] array, int val, int count) {
    Result result = new Result(count);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            //check if pair values add to given sum
            if (array[i] + array[j] == val) {
                int[] temp = new int[2];
                temp[0] = array[i];
                temp[1] = array[j];
                result.pairs[index++] = temp;
                result.noOfPairs++;
                count--;
                if (count == 0) {
                    //we got required no of pairs..now exit
                    result.isSum = true;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The patch is a bit ugly - but it works, if there's such two elements - the result will return the indexes of these elements in the array:

```
public static int[] isSum(int[] a,int val,int count,int index, int[] arr){
    int[] res = new int[2];
    if(count == 0 && val ==0){
        return arr;
    }
    else if(index >=a.length || count == 0) {
        return res;
    }
    else{
        res[0] = arr[0];
        res[1] = arr[1];
        if(count==1){
            arr[1] = index;
        }
        else{
            arr[0] = index;
        }
        int[] s1 = isSum(a,val-a[index],count-1,index+1, arr);
        int[] s2 = isSum(a,val,count,index+1, res);
        res = (s1[1] != 0 ? s1 : s2);
    }
    return res;
}

public static void main(String...args){
    int[] a = {1,11,4,7,8,10};
    int[] s = new int[2];
    int [] res = isSum(a, 21, 2, 0, s);
    System.out.println("result: "+(res[1] != 0));
    if((res[1] > 0)){
        System.out.print(res[0]+" "+res[1]);
    }
}
```

**OUPUT**

```
result: true
1 5
```

---

Another (and more elegant) way:

```
public static int[] isSum(int[] a,int val){
    int[] res = new int[2];
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        int tmp = a[i];
        int index = search(a, val-tmp);
        if(index != -1){
            return new int[] {i, index};//success
        }
    }
    return res;//failure
}

private static int search(int[] a, int val) {
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if (a[i] == val) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String...args){
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,11,4,7,10};
    int[] res = isSum(arr, 21);
    System.out.println("res: {"+res[0]+","+res[1]+"}");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> res: {3,6}

Comment: if i pass the count in the signature it would not do that.

Comment: Example - a[] = {1,3,4,10}
    Signature- isSum(a,15,2,0)

Comment: @SindhujaNarasimhan indeed you pass the count in the signature - but you didn't add a check to see that it's not > 2 (in that scenario you should return `false` oc)

Comment: Change the example that you posted above to: Example = {1,12,4,7,8,10} Sum - 21. And it'll still return true since: 4+7+10 = 21

Comment: why does it qualify as a bug? if i stick to this way of writing the signature I can pass any count value and return the elements that account to that count.

Comment: The requirement the way you posted it: "array has 2 numbers that account to a sum". The program returns TRUE even if there are no such 2 number. Either the requirement is not clear or there's a bug ;)

Comment: i think you should consider scaling the code than discussing about the requirement. This is a better way to write code and works for any input of count and sum

Comment: what is the run time of the second solution? It looks very intuitive

Comment: @SindhujaNarasimhan O(n^2). It can be improved a bit by adding another parameter to `search()` that will hold the "first index to start looking from" - and start from `i+1`. But it still won't change the magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the return type to (for example) an array, then
you have to catch the returning result not return it directly, and if it's true capture the values by the given index then returning them in an array, and if it's false return a null array... testing the values of the returned array you will know if it's true or false and also will give you the values you need if it's true.

**UPDATE:**

```
public static int[] isSum(int[] a, int val, int count, int index) {
int[] results = new int[2];
results[0] = -1;
results[1] = -1;

if (count == 0 && val == 0) {
    results[0] = 0;
    results[1] = 0;
    return results;
}
if (index >= a.length)
    return results;
else {

    if (isSum(a, val - a[index], count - 1, index + 1) == results) {
        if (isSum(a, val, count, index + 1) == results) {
            return results;
        } else {
            results[0] = val;
            results[1] = a[index + 1];
            return results;
        }
    } else {
        results[0] = val - a[index];
        results[1] = a[index + 1];
        return results;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: can you show the example in code if it is not much trouble? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isSum(int[] arr,int val){
   int a,b=0;
   int c=0,d=0;
   boolean bol=false;
   for(a=0;a<arr.length;a++)
   {
       b=a+1;

   while(b<arr.length)
   {

       System.out.println(a+" "+b);

   if(arr[a]+arr[b]==val)
   {
       System.out.println(arr[a]+arr[b]);
   bol=true;
   c=a;
   d=b;
   break;
   }
   else
       b++;

   }

   }
   System.err.println(c+" "+d);
       return bol ;
    }
}
```